# correlated sub-queries,aggregates and grouping

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having an issue with a query, I'm using postgresql 9.2.

I have created a view which returns a key value, a timestamp, and an interval that look like this:

```
select * from foo.a;  -- My view and the results

 k  |         ts1            |  tm
 1  | 2011-12-08 06:46:00+00 | 01:00:00
 1  | 2011-12-08 09:14:00+00 | 01:00:00
 2  | 2011-12-08 02:00:00+00 | 02:00:00
 2  | 2011-12-08 05:00:00+00 | 02:00:00
 4  | 2011-12-08 10:06:00+00 | 02:00:00
 4  | 2011-12-08 13:31:00+00 | 02:00:00
 1  | 2011-12-11 03:00:00+00 | 01:00:00
 1  | 2011-12-11 04:49:00+00 | 02:00:00
 4  | 2011-12-11 10:06:00+00 | 02:00:00
 4  | 2011-12-11 13:31:00+00 | 02:00:00
```

I have about 8,000 rows in my results. Now, I want to sum the interval's and group by key, so I do this:

```
select k,
       sum(tm) as tm
  from foo.a
group by k;
```

As expected my results are:

```
k   |  tm
1   | 5:00
2   | 4:00
4   | 8:00
```

I want to take it a step further and do this (the error - ERROR: subquery uses ungrouped column 'ts1' from outer query).

```
select k,
       sum(tm) as tm,
       (select sum(tm) where ts1 > '2011-12-09')
        -- (select sum(tm) where ts1 > '2012-01-01')
        -- I need to the above on 5 different dates. 
  from foo.a
  group by k,
```

Desired results are:

```
k    |   tm   |  tm1
1    |  5:00  |  3:00
2    |  4:00  |  
4    |  8:00  |  4:00
```

If I add ts1 into my group clause, it doesn't return desired results, naturally - because I don't want to group by ts1, only k. I can use ts1 in an aggregate function and the query will run with undesirable results.

This works:

```
select foo.a.k,
       bar.tm1,
       sum(tm)
  from foo.a
  left join
      (select k,
              sum(tm) as tm1
         from foo.a
        where foo.a.ts1 > '2011-12-09'
        group by k) as bar
  on foo.a.k = bar.k
  group by foo.a.k,
           bar.tm1;
```

But querying the same view for the same information seems wrong and unnecessary. Especially, since I have to do this 5 times.

My question: Is there a work-around for performing a correlated-query on an ungrouped column? If not, what is a better approach to achieving my desired results?

Comment: Check the query plan. Views are handled as if they were witten out literally before they are drawn into the query. This will (in most cases) result in excellent plans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select k,
       sum(tm) as tm,
       sum(case when ts1 > '2012-01-01' then tm else 0 end) as tm_20120101
from foo.a
group by k
```

Comment: You got it. I didn't even think of using case within sum(). Thanks so much!